# MKNetworkKit - tracking status of frozen operations / onCompletion & onError not called

Tags: ios5, network-programming

One of the many great features of the MKNetworkKit library is how easy it makes "freezing" http POST requests (such as uploading to a server) that can be auto-resumed later when network connectivity is restored.

Details here:
  http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/#Operation_freezing

But as I'm wrapping up my MKNetworkKit based app, I've discovered that the onCompletion and onError blocks do not get called on a frozen network transaction (this is apparently a known issue), and I am struggling how to build a UI around this that lets the user know when a frozen transaction actually completes.

Has anyone dealt with this situation?

What is the best way to keep a user oblivious to network drops and downtime, but to still be able to give some feedback around when then last successful connection was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer I came up with was to subclass the MKNetworkOperation, and to then override operationSucceeded and operationFailedWithError.  These routines are still called when a frozen operation completes.

From the MKNetworkOperation.h header file:

```
/*!
 *  @abstract Overridable custom method where you can add your custom business logic error handling
 *  
 *  @discussion
 *  This optional method can be overridden to do custom error handling. Be sure to call [super operationSucceeded] at the last.
 *  For example, a valid HTTP response (200) like "Item not found in database" might have a custom business error code
 *  You can override this method and called [super failWithError:customError]; to notify that HTTP call was successful but the method
 *  ended as a failed call
 *
 */
-(void) operationSucceeded;

/*!
 *  @abstract Overridable custom method where you can add your custom business logic error handling
 *  
 *  @discussion
 *  This optional method can be overridden to do custom error handling. Be sure to call [super operationSucceeded] at the last.
 *  For example, a invalid HTTP response (401) like "Unauthorized" might be a valid case in your app.
 *  You can override this method and called [super operationSucceeded]; to notify that HTTP call failed but the method
 *  ended as a success call. For example, Facebook login failed, but to your business implementation, it's not a problem as you
 *  are going to try alternative login mechanisms.
 *
 */
-(void) operationFailedWithError:(NSError*) error;
```